# Having tough time converting Swift method to C#

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift, unity-game-engine

I am writing iOS plugins for Unity.
I need to call the function below from Unity. The target function is written in Swift.

How can I convert Swift completion block/closure to C#.
What should I write in place of `completionHandler`?

```
#if UNITY_IOS
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void initializeSDK(string name, string apiKey, completionHandler );  
#endif
```

```
static func init(name: String?, apiKey: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // do some stuffs..
    completionHandler(status) // status is of Bool type.
}
```

also based on suggestions which i have received, i have updated code:
updated code as below, i am getting compile errors in ios side.
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

2nd suggestion i have tried for which i am getting crash:
attaching images of code snip for reference.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about `Action<bool>`?

Comment: whats equivallent of 'completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)' in c# ?

Comment: As `completionHandler` is a closure, it would be a delegate type in C#. So, I think `Action<bool>` would be appropriate here.

Comment: @SrejonKhan, how can i write the same swift function in c#? As i am not familiar with c# much.

Comment: is this correct way to call method: init("myApp1","122332443",completionHandler ( bool status ) { Debug.Log(status); });

Comment: i got following error: https://pastebin.com/TkHsSfm5

Comment: i got a crash, https://pastebin.com/Lf9c5ehH

Comment: Make your `runNativeCode()` method static and check again.

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec: i am getting some errors in ios side, i have included screenshots in question. can you review it.

Comment: @Milan, thank you very much for your help. All issues solved, callback function working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with Unity, include a MonoPInvokeCallback attribute decorated method. So, your definition would look like this:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void initializeSDK( string name, string apiKey, Action<bool> completionHandler );
```

And your callback method would look like this:

```
[MonoPInvokeCallback ( typeof ( Action<bool> ) )]
private static void completionHandler ( bool success )
{
    Debug.Log ( $"completionHandler ({success})" );
}
```

And to start the ball rolling, you would call your plugin method like so:

```
initializeSDK("myApp1","122332443",completionHandler);
```

---

Full Code:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using AOT;
  
public static class AwesomeShow
{
#if UNITY_IOS 
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void AwesomeSDK_runNativeCode(string name);
 
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    static extern long AwesomeSDK_toNumber(string numberString); 
 
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void AwesomeSDK_initializeSDK(string name, string apiKey,  Action<bool> completionHandler); 
#endif

    [MonoPInvokeCallback ( typeof ( Action<bool> ) )]
    private static void completionHandler ( bool success )
    {
        Debug.Log ( "result is: " + success );
    }

    public static void RunNativeCode ( string name )
    {
#if UNITY_IOS
        AwesomeSDK_runNativeCode(name);
        Debug.Log("number is " + AwesomeSDK_toNumber("30")); 
        AwesomeSDK_initializeSDK("myApp1","122332443",completionHandler);
#else
        Debug.Log ( "No ios device" );
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: is this correct way to call method:  initializeSDK("myApp1","122332443",completionHandler ( bool status ) {
            Debug.Log(status);
        });

Comment: @Matrix sorry, I've edited the answer to call the method correctly.

Comment: i got following error: https://pastebin.com/TkHsSfm5

Comment: @Matrix are you sure you made the callback method a `static` method? All managed methods that are called from native code must be static methods.

Comment: ok, i will change it to static.

Comment: i got a crash after making it static. no other information available for crash.

Comment: wait, i will attach file contents.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Lf9c5ehH

Comment: i feel something wrong here: @_cdecl("AwesomeSDK_initializeSDK")
public func AwesomeSDK_initializeSDK(_ name: UnsafePointer<CChar>?,
                          _ apiKey: UnsafePointer<CChar>?,
                          _ completionHandler: @escaping (CBool) -> Void) {
you can see it in above pastebin link

Comment: @Matrix I've included code in the answer for the method. I would keep it in a separate class (not inheriting MonoBehaviour) so the IL2CPP doesn't get confused at all. That might be an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247628/discussion-between-matrix-and-milan-egon-votrubec).

Comment: i have posted a screenshot in above chat link, i am still getting crash, i feel something wrong in '@escaping (CBool) -> Void)'.

Comment: i think i need to convert: @convention(c) (UnsafePointer<CBool>) -> Void to closure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520975/convention-to-closure-in-swift

Comment: `MonoPInvokeCallback`...ooh I learnt something new today. +1   :)

Comment: @Matrix _"i got following error"_ - please feel free to post that as a new question as I feel Milan's answer is the best.  Please take note of _["Looks like <refer to original problem> is solved isn't it? As for <refer to "next" problem>, that would be a different question, consider posting it separately."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/585968)_

Comment: does this looks correct? :https://postimg.cc/LncRF5vt

Comment: https://postimg.cc/QKxf9Qb2

Comment: @MickyD: i am getting errors in ios side, i have posted screenshots in question, can you review it.

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec, thank you very much, all issues solved now.