# how to call a function with callback, which actually calls from unity to ios and get response back in unity?

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

i have an ios framework (written in swift), i need to write unity plugins for it.

framework has one callback method, like

init(appid: String, completionBlock:(Bool) -> Void)

so from unity i need to call above method and also unity should get call back with 'bool' kind of status.

please note: this method is from framework, so it may not have access to UIViewController.(/UIKit).

I have tried using normal function, but function which supposed to callback unity, and it may not have access to UIKit.

Comment: i don't think its deleted: you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518201/having-tough-time-converting-swift-method-to-c-sharp

Comment: Apologies, not sure why I couldn't find it before.