# How do I return a parameter from a callback in Swift to Unity?

Tags: c, swift, unity-game-engine, plugins, bridge

I am writing a iOS plugin for Unity in Swift, using a bridge in C. It looks something like this:

Unity (C#):

```
public class PluginHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern double IOS_getVersion();

    private void Start()
    {
        double result = IOS_getVersion();
        Debug.Log(result);
    }
```

C:

```
\#import \<Foundation/Foundation.h\>
\#include "UnityFramework/UnityFramework-Swift.h"

extern "C" {

double IOS_getVersion(){
double result = \[\[UnityPlugin shared\] swift_getVersion\];
return result;
}
}
```

Swift:

```
@objc public class UnityPlugin : NSObject {

    @objc public static let shared = UnityPlugin()
    
    @objc public func swift_getVersion() -> Double{
        let result =  (some code)
        return result
    }

}
```

This works fine. Now, I have a function in Swift which registers a callback. When the callback is called in swift, it returns some values. I want those values to get to Unity.  How can I do this?

The function looks like this:

```
public static func swiftfunction(target: AnyObject, handler: @escaping ((Notification?) -\> Void)) -\> NSObjectProtocol
```

Comment: In the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html there is a section: *Calling C# back from native code*. Maybe also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73518754/2331445.